# upgrading 14.04 to 15.04 fails with infinite loop

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

After accepting all the prompts for the upgrade from 14.04.03 to 15.04, the laptop (Lenovo T540p) the new OS fails to boot!!! It gets stuck in an infinite loop starting System Logging Service and failing, trying again and failing, trying again and failing.... This cannot be broken out of. Can anyone offer a suggestion for breaking out of this infinite loop, getting to a point where I can use the laptop?

Thanks

Comment: Sincerely, at this point it's better to reinstall. By the way, 16.04 will be released in 3 months and is an LTS. Why don't you wait to upgrade?

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, in the meantime, I have a completely unusable laptop courtesy of Ubuntu. Should never have installed the distro. I'll make a point of sticking to Fedora, or any other distro in future.

Comment: Well, that's sad. But we usually keep an LTS when we have one.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu **15.04** is *end-of-life* this month (Jan-2016).

To upgrade from **14.04 LTS** (to 15.04) would only have been supported via **14.10** (which is no longer supported).

**What you were attempting is NOT supported.**

---

You need to re-install either Ubuntu **14.04 LTS** or **15.10** ..

**Note:** *If you do NOT already have backup of any data (or settings), then you need to recover that data BEFORE the new install.*

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If this is the case, then why does Ubuntu prompt the user to select that upgrade? If as you say, this upgrade is not supported then it should not be offered.